# GDB step over function (next) doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm trying to debug a program I wrote in C++. Here is the code:

```
void a() { }
void b() { a(); }
int main() { b(); return 0; }
```

I compiled it using: `g++ -g3 -O0 -o cards.exe cards.cpp`.

Here is the output of my GDB session:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401421: file cards.cpp, line 10.
(gdb) r
Starting program: C:\workspace\Cards\src/cards.exe
[New thread 1624.0xa28]
Breakpoint 1, main () at cards.cpp:10
10    int main()
(gdb) n
12        b();
(gdb) n
b () at cards.cpp:5 5
void b()
(gdb) n
7        a();
(gdb) quit
The program is running.  Exit anyway? (y or n)
```

Why does sending a next command to GDB still step into a function?

I'm using g++ 4.2.1-sjlj and GDB 6.8.

Comment: Have you tried something more complex?

Comment: Actually yes, I have tried making looped invocations to a(). Still won't work. I have also tried disabling inlining with __attribute__((noinline)) but to no avail. I have tried this on my Hackintosh and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

The `step` and `next` commands work one source line at a time, so when everything is all on one line a single `next` takes me right to the end of `main()`.

```
3    int main() { b(); return 0; }
(gdb) n
0x00001faa in start ()
```

With the code formatted less densely I still do not see the results you see. I put the function calls on separate lines to get GDB to step over them one at a time. Here's what I get then:

```
jkugelman$ cat cards.cpp
```

```
void a() {
}

void b() {
    a();
}

int main() {
    b();
    return 0;
}
```

```
jkugelman$ g++ -g3 -O0 -o cards cards.cpp
jkugelman$ gdb ./cards
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-960) (Sun May 18 18:38:33 UTC 2008)
<snip>
Reading symbols for shared libraries .... done

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1ff2: file cards.cpp, line 9.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/jkugelman/Development/StackOverflow/cards
Reading symbols for shared libraries +++. done

Breakpoint 1, main () at cards.cpp:9
9        b();
(gdb) n
10        return 0;
(gdb) n
11    }
(gdb) n
0x00001faa in start ()
```

I don't have an answer, but I just wanted to share that GDB behaves as expected on my [iMac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac). In either case GDB treated the call to `b()` as one instruction and never entered the function call.

Comment: I tried using your code but step over still doesn't work on it. Maybe because we're using different versions of gdb?

Comment: What do `help next` and `help step` say on your machine?

Comment: (gdb) help next
Step program, proceeding through subroutine calls.
Like the "step" command as long as subroutine calls do not happen;
when they do, the call is treated as one instruction.
Argument N means do this N times (or till program stops for another reason).
(gdb) help step
Step program until it reaches a different source line.
Argument N means do this N times (or till program stops for another reason).

Comment: setting the debug symbol format to STABS seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score -2):

'n' is the `next` statement and will not step into the function.

For stepping into the function, use 's'. That is `step`.

Comment: no. `n` DOES step into the function. that is the very problem OP is addressing.